# HTML source while webscraping seems inconsistent for website

Tags: python, python-3.x

I checked out say:

https://www.calix.com/search-results.html?searchKeyword=C7

And if I inspect element on the first link I get this:

```
<a class="title viewDoc" 
href="https://www.calix.com/content/dam/calix/mycalix- 
misc/ed-svcs/learning_paths/C7_lp.pdf" data- 
preview="/session/4e14b237-f19b-47dd-9bb5-d34cc4c4ce01/" 
data-preview-count="1" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-file- 
pdf-o grn"></i><b>C7</b> Learning Path</a>
```

I coded:

```
import requests, bs4
res = requests.get('https://www.calix.com/search-results.html? 
searchKeyword=C7',headers={'User-Agent':'test'})
print(res)
#res.raise_for_status()
bs_obj= bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
elems=bs_obj.findAll('a',attrs={"class","title viewDoc"})
print(elems)
```

And there was [] as output (empty list).

So, I thought about actually looking through the "view-source" for the page.

view-source:https://www.calix.com/search-results.html?searchKeyword=C7

If you search through the "view-source" you will not find the code for the "inspect element" I mentioned earlier.

There is no "a class="title viewDoc"" in the view-source of the page.

That is probably why my code isn't returning anything.

The I went to www.nba.com, and inspected a link

```
<a class="content_list--item clearfix" 
href="/article/2018/07/07/demarcus-cousins-discusses- 
stacked-golden-state-warriors-roster"><h5 class="content_list- 
-title">Cousins on Warriors' potential: 'Scary'</h5><time 
class="content_list--time">in 5 hours</time></a>
```

The content of "inspect" for this link was in the "view-source" of the page.

And, obviously my code was working for this page.

I have seen a few examples of issue #1.

Just curious why the difference in html formats, or am I missing something?

Comment: Ummm what immediately stands out is that... `{"class","title viewDoc"}` is a `set`... have you tried `{"class": "title viewDoc"}` which is a `dict` instead? Might not be the issue but certainly isn't correct to start with.

Comment: (and a side note: `.findAll` is deprecated... you should get into he habit of using `.find_all` moving forward)

Comment: Tried both >"class":"title viewDoc" and >find_all.
I think the issue is the format of the html page.
If I search for anything in the nba.com webpage it works just fine.
But the calix.com webpage doesn't.

Comment: Have you checked the raw source in your browser which'll be before any javascript executes to check what you're looking for isn't dynamically generated?

Comment: Its worth mentioning that viewing the page source and inspecting elements will yield different results. I believe this is because the page source is the response received from the server which doesn't include any post page load dom changes. You should always base your scraping on the "inspect element" dom.

Comment: @Sal errr... you should always base it on the raw source received - *not* what the developer tools inspection stuff shows.

Comment: What if it's an angular site, post loading everything client-side?

Comment: By raw source do you mean "view-source:https://www.calix.com/search-results.html?searchKeyword=C7"?
If yes, then as I mentioned in my post I dont see any reference of "a class="title viewDoc"". 
So, "inspect element" and "view source" are not showing the same thing.

Comment: The request that I use is "res = requests.get('https://www.calix.com/search-results.html?searchKeyword=C7',headers={'User-Agent':'test'})"

This is downloading the page under "page-source".
That is what I see when I print res.text

But page source doesnt have the "Inspect element" that I am looking for.